# Entity Framework: C# Winforms bindingsource delete on datagridview, but tag isDeleted field as true only (not delete)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I am currently working on a C# Winforms application with Entity Framework 5.

My problem is how to do a delete (which only tag `isDeleted` field as `true`) to an item on the `bindingsource` binded to an `entity`.

This is a screenshot of my form:

[image: Enroll Medication Form]

The `DataGridView` is bound to `enrollmedsBindingSource`. See this code of form load which fills the binding source:

```
    private void EnrollMedicationFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.enrollmeds.Where(adm => adm.FK_Admission == _SelectedPKAdm && adm.isDeleted == false).ToList();
        enrollmedsBindingSource.DataSource = context.enrollmeds.Local;
    }
```

As you can see on the above code, I filtered the data to display only the data which `isDeleted` is set to false.

Below is the code for my delete button:

```
    private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enrollmedsDataGridView.CurrentRow == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No item selected.", "System Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            enrollmedsBindingSource.Remove(enrollmedsBindingSource.Current);
        }
    }
```

This code removes the item from the database if I call `context.SaveChanges();` on save button.

Below is the code for save button:

```
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.enrollmedsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        context.enrollmeds.Local
            .Where(a => a.C__PK_EnrollMeds == 0)
            .ToList().ForEach(i =>
            {
                i.FK_DC_Patient = pxdetails.pxDC.PK_Datacenter;
                i.FK_DC_userAdd = mainfrm.PK_DC_UserLoggedIn;
                i.AddDateTime = currdatetime;
                i.FK_Admission = pxdetails.adm.PK_Admission;
            });
        this.context.SaveChanges();
        enrollmedsDataGridView.Refresh();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

What I want to do, is to remove the entry on the `DataGridView` *(from user's view)* but only tag the `isDeleted` field is `true` in the database *(for audit purposes)*.

**Note:**
*The save button only clicked once the user is done on all the changes, so the form need to capture what is deleted (`isDeleted`), changed, and added upon saving.*

Comment: You need to set `IsDeleted` to `true` then `SaveChanges` and then reload data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `IsDeleted` property of your entity to `true` and the call `SaveChanges`. For example, if you have a `Product` entity:

```
var p = (Product)bindingSource.Current;
p.IsDeleted = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Then if you are not going to reload data, you can remove the item from list to not show it:

```
bs.RemoveCurrent();
db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Or you can reload data:

```
db.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Load();
bindingSource.DataSource = db.Products.Local;
```

**Note**

If you are not going to save changes immediately, you need to do something else after setting `IsDeletet` to `true`:

- You can stop working connected to context and use a [`BindingList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) or [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) for data-binding and track data changes yourself. Then you can simply have a list of deleted items to set their `IsDeleted` property to `true` when saving changes.
- As another option, after setting `IsDeleetd` to true, you can change the appearance of deleted rows in `DataGridView`. For example, you can handle `RowPostPaint` event of `DataGridView` and draw a red strikeout like over the row.

Comment: Hi @Reza, Thanks for answering my question. Tried your answer but not working as my `db.SaveChanges();` called only on the save button, which only clicked once the user is done on the changes. I think the `db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;` code loses the track on the changes of the entity which why upon saving there are no changes saved. If I remove the `db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;` the item will be deleted. :( 
Thank you very much bro @Reza :)

Comment: Hi, you're welcome :) `db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;` will detach the entity and the context will no more track the entity.

Comment: Hi @Reza, do you have any workaround to do this on entityframework? I'm at lost on this :( I know that the binding will take care of the changes on the entity, If there is a way to escape the delete part on the binding so I can make a separate process on the deleted item (`isDeleted`).

Comment: As a workaround I prefer to just render deleted item in a different way, for example by changing the color, backcolor, or even draw a strikeout line on it. Then after save changes, reload data to remove them from grid.

Comment: Thank you very much @Reza, you gave me idea on your workaround :) instead of changing the backcolor or strikeout the row, I made the row hidden and it worked :) The row still on the binding (which will not be deleted) however it is hidden to the user (just as what I want to happen). Thank you again for the great technique :) I will mark your solution as the answer :) Thanks again bro :) :) :)